# After 2.9.3 update tons of errors related “relationship_parser/VariableFinder.php”

Tags: relationships, grid, update

After updaiting to EE 2.9.3 some my sites get many-many errors like this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Uninitialized string offset: 19096
Filename: relationship_parser/VariableFinder.php
Line Number: 109
```

Some googling revealed that probably Grid filetype and obviously relationships are involved.

Do i need change something in templates, is some syntax changed?

Everything on web page works as it should.

Comment: This is why you never jump on the "update right away" band wagon... probably a bug. If the site is functioning as expected, just make sure Debug is set to off (0 in the config) so no visitors see the notices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug.  I've seen it on another project I wasn't working on and one just now that I am.

I think the problem stems from a Grid-within-a-relationship or vice-versa.  I fixed the first way by splitting the tag into an embed (and passing entry_ids into it), but on my project I had to update the core files, which I hate.

If you ever HAVE TO update core code, I always recommend commenting with a universal token "MYCOMPANYNAME_DEV" so they can be searched for before an upgrade, along with your initials, date, and a description of what you've done (and wherever possible, keep the old code commented out).

I updated the lineToCharacterOffsets method in the VariableFinder.php file, found in /system/expressionengine/libraries/relationship_parser

The line before:

```
if ($str[$offset] == "\n") {
```

put this:

```
if ($offset > strlen($str)) {
    $offset = strlen($str);
    break;
}
```

It's looking for a linebreak beyond the scope of the string (a string being just an array of char), so I just give it the end of the string and tell it to move on.  It seems to do the trick, but hopefully this will be picked up and remedied soon.